# Using ∞ as an algebraic term

Tags: infinity

Would it ever be possible to use ∞ as an algebraic term, putting it in equations with non infinite terms, incorporating a coefficient? Would a new type of infinity need to be defined or could aleph null work?

Comment: See, for example, [hyperrreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) and [transfinite numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot different approaches, depending on what you want to do. In analysis for example, the notion of the [extended reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) is useful, for example in the context of measure theory when you want a meaningful way to say "this set $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ has infinite measure."

Formally, the extended reals $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty,-\infty\},$ equipped with partially defined arithmetic operations $+,-,\times,\div.$ In particular we have the following additional operations,
\begin{align*}
  a \pm \infty &= \pm\infty, \\
  \infty + \infty &= \infty \\
  b \times \infty &= \infty, \\
  (-1) \times \infty &= - \infty, \\
  a \div \infty &= 0 \\
  b \div 0 &= \infty \\
\end{align*}
for $a,b \in \mathbb R$ with $b>0.$ Note that some expressions are simply left undefined, such as $\infty - \infty.$

Informally speaking, the idea behind analysis is to study infinitesimal changes by thinking of them as limits of finite operations. For example the idea that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin x / x = 1$ is that for very small values of $x,$ we have $\sin x / x$ is very close to $1.$ One way to motivate the above definitions is to observe that if we replace each occurrence of $\infty$ by $x$ and each occurrence of $0$ by $\varepsilon$ in the above, taking limits $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ we reach those expressions. So from this limit perspective, the above definitions are the "correct" rules arithmetic with $\infty$ should satisfy.

However for example the limit of $a - b$ when both $a$ and $b$ are sent to infinity is ambiguous, depending on how quickly $a$ and $b$ grows in relation to each other. This in a way is why we leave it undefined.

---

As the other comments and answers show, there are a lot of other ways of giving meaning to $\infty$ and ways of doing arithmetic with them. I would like to stress that there is no single correct way to define it, and that different approaches are useful for different things. For a very different (and very interesting) approach for example, see [ordinal arithmetic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic)

Comment: @Mandy R it's also worth noting that depending on what we wish to model, the arithmetical rules for the extended reals can be modified. For example, in measure theory generally we define $0 \times \infty = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

In order: yes, yes, yes, no, no.

$\infty$ *is* an algebraic term which can occur in equations, it just isn't a very interesting one.
For example: $2\infty=\infty$, $\infty+1=\infty$, and $\infty/2=\infty$ are all perfectly viable, they just don't mean anything.

Outside of this, $\infty$ can be used as an algebraic term via [points at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity). If you want, you can also *define* $\infty$ in such a way as to treat it like a number, but this is not advisable. $\aleph_0$ is the cardinal number defined as the cardinality of the set of all natural numbers. I would not use it as an algebraic term.